# XSLT: Using xsl:key in nested XML structures

Tags: xslt

**EXAMPLE**

Here is an example from MSDN. It show how to transform a XML file into HTML using `xsl:key`.

**Example XML (input)**

```
<books>
  <book title="XML Today" author="David Perry" release="2016"/>
  <book title="XML and Microsoft" author="David Perry" release="2015"/>
  <book title="XML Productivity" author="Jim Kim" release="2015"/>
</books>
```

**Example XSL (input)**

```
<xsl:key name="title-search" match="book" use="@author"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
   <HTML>
      <BODY>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('title-search', 'David Perry')">
         <DIV>
         <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
         </DIV>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </BODY>
   </HTML>
</xsl:template>
```

**Example HTML (output)**

```
<HTML>
  <BODY>
    <DIV>XML Today</DIV>
    <DIV>XML and Microsoft</DIV>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

**MY PROBLEM**

I would like to produce the same HTML output but using a different XML input. How should the corresponding XSL file look like?

**My XML (input)**

```
<books>
  <book>
    <a n="author"><s>David Perry</s></a>
    <a n="title"><s>XML Today</s></a>
    <a n="release"><i>2016</i></a>
  </book>
  <book>
    <a n="author"><s>David Perry</s></a>
    <a n="title"><s>XML and Microsoft</s></a>
    <a n="release"><i>2015</i></a>
  </book>
  <book>
    <a n="author"><s>Jim Kim</s></a>
    <a n="title"><s>XML Productivity</s></a>
    <a n="release"><i>2015</i></a>
  </book>
</books>
```

**My XSL (input)**

```
???
```

**My HTML (output)**

```
<HTML>
  <BODY>
    <DIV>XML Today</DIV>
    <DIV>XML and Microsoft</DIV>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, your key matched `book` elements by their `author` attribute, but in the new XML, you want to match them by the `a` element where the `n` attribute is "author", so the key looks like this.

```
<xsl:key name="title-search" match="book" use="a[@n='author']/s"/>
```

Then, to get the title for the a matched `book` you would do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="a[@n='title']/s"/>
```

Therefore your XSLT would look like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" />

    <xsl:key name="title-search" match="book" use="a[@n='author']/s"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <HTML>
          <BODY>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('title-search', 'David Perry')">
             <DIV>
             <xsl:value-of select="a[@n='title']/s"/>
             </DIV>
          </xsl:for-each>
          </BODY>
       </HTML>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could actually drop the `/s` in the expressions here, if the `s` element was only ever going to be the only element under each `a` element.

This would work too:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" />

    <xsl:key name="title-search" match="book" use="a[@n='author']"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <HTML>
          <BODY>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('title-search', 'David Perry')">
             <DIV>
             <xsl:value-of select="a[@n='title']"/>
             </DIV>
          </xsl:for-each>
          </BODY>
       </HTML>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basic XSLT transformation, you can do something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="book"> 
  <div> 
  Author: <xsl:value-of select="a[@n='author']/s" />
  title: <xsl:value-of select="a[@n='title']/s" >
  release: <xsl:value-of select="a[@n='release']/s" >
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```